# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for Type

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a `LoginCrudService` with dependency as

```
   @Inject
    public LoginCrudService(@Nonnull @LoginService final EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);
    }
```

where `@LoginService` is correctly pointing to right interface

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface LoginService {
}
```

When I deploy this on `JBoss AS 7.1`, I see

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@LoginService] at injection point [[parameter 1] of [constructor] @Inject public com.myorg.bb.persistence.LoginCrudService(EntityManager)]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:275)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:244)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:346)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:331)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception 0 :
```

What does this error means? and how can I fix it?

Comment: do you have a working producer deployed for the qualified EM?

Comment: what you mean by working producer?

Comment: I mean a public method returning an `EntityManager`, annotated both with `@Produces` and `@LoginService`. `Parameter 1` mentioned in the error is the `@LoginService` qualifier, so it seems to be sth wrong with the producing side.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have missing libraries for your application.

The exception should be uncovered by examining the JBoss server log which resides at *JBOSS_HOME*/standalone/log/server.log